# MVC3 Custom Route to hide action

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a routing question that i have been tinkering with but have been unsuccessful in trying to get it to work.

Basically, i have the default route in my global.asax file and i have the following controller with the following  actions:

Controller = People
Actions = Index & Search

When you visit the People page you get a search box, when you run a search, the form GETS to:

http://mysite/people/search?filter=a&searchType=IdentityCode&searchOption=StartsWith

What i would like to do is, drop the **search** in the url, so it will look something like this:

http://mysite/people?filter=a&searchtype=IdentityCode&searchOption=StartsWith

But still run the search action.

Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by making index and search the same method.

```
public ActionResult Index(string filter, string searchType, string searchOption)
{

   IList<Person> people;

   if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter)) {
       people = peopleRepo.GetAll(); // Get all the people, or none - whatever you prefer on the index page
   }
   else
   {
       people = peopleRepo.Search(filter, searchType, searchOption);
   }

   Return View("index", people);

}
```

Obviously I have taken license interpreting your code, but I hope you get the idea.